# Show Array in React JS component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

I'm pretty new to ReactJS and I hope somebody can help me.

I get a JSON object from an API and would like to show some of the informations in my component.

The object looks some kind of this:

```
{
  name: Tom,
  types: [
          {
            slot: 1,
            type: {url: xyz, name: TomsURL}
          },
          {
           slot: 2,
           type: {url: zyz, name: OtherName
          }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Now I would like to show some of the data in my components.
The Component 'Body' contains the request method and sends the fetched data by props to the Layout Component

```
export default class Body extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        person: ""
    }
}

handleSubmit(e){
    getRequest.fetchData()
    .then(function(response){
        if(response.status === 404){
            alert("Unbekannter Name");
        }else{
            this.setState(function(){
                return {
                    person: response.data
                }
            })    
        }
    }.bind(this));
}

render() {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Form handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
            <Layout person={this.state.person}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

This is the Layout component where I want to show the data:

```
export default class Layout extends Component {

render() {
    var person= this.props.person
    return ( 
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>{person.name}</li>
                <li>{person.types[0].type.name}</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

If I try to start the App I get the error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

I think this is because there is no data to show in that component until I request the data by a button click. Before I press the button I want to just show the app without data and afterwards it should update

Comment: because the initial value of `person` is `''` in the state value, do one thing put the check inside render method of `Layout` like this: `render(){if(!Array.isArray(person) return null; return(.... other code......))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person is an Object, right? If that's the case you should set it as an empty Object (not a string) on the constructor to keep things consistent.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        person: {}
    }
}
```

Now what you need to do in order to only display the info when it's available and leave it blank otherwise is to check against the person property having info (aka not being an empty object).

```
export default class Layout extends Component {

render() {
    var person = this.props.person
    if (Object.values(person).length !== 0) {
      return ( 
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>{person.name}</li>
                <li>{person.types[0].type.name}</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition in your `render` function

```
   <div>
        <Form handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
        {this.state.person ? <Layout person={this.state.person}/> : null}
    </div>
```

Comment: The problem of doing it this way is that you aren't showing the Layout at all (not sure if the Layout has anything else or it is just a blank space) and OP said he wanted the app without data (that's why I did check inside the Layout component).

Comment: @Rodius yes, agree, but in this case looks like your variant will work in the same way

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should map through your entire person JSON object, and pull out the specific data you need.

Before you pass in the person object as props to the Layout Component you loop through it using the `map()` function

```
export default class Body extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        persons: [] // This should be an empty array by default
    }
}

handleSubmit(e){
    getRequest.fetchData()
    .then(function(response){
        if(response.status === 404){
            alert("Unbekannter Name");
        }else{
            this.setState(function(){
                return {
                    persons: response.data
                }
            })    
        }
    }.bind(this));
}

render() {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Form handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
            this.state.persons.map((person, i) => {
               <Layout key={i} person={person}/>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I think this is not necessary because I will always have only one person by each API request. So I need only to pass one object